# Is it possible to open a new calendar appointment, like the mailto tag but for calendar?

Tags: php, outlook, calendar, mailto, appointment

I was just wondering if there is a way of doing this so the mail client opens up with the Calendar and you can half fill out the details. I don't want to just silently create it and send it i want the window to pop up with the calendar appointment screen and the can edit as necessary.

I am using PHP and Outlook 2010.

Thank you in advance!

Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the iCal specifications... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Comment: I agree I've looked around and this seems to be the way to do it BUT i don't want to create the file silently i would like Outlook to open and have this new appointment as the appointment being edited.

Do you know if this is possible?

Thank you for your speedy response :)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible from a URI, you'd probably need to be calling the API to get that level of functionality and given your mention of PHP I suspect this is a web page that you want triggering the action.